# Atribuir um valor a checkbox em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formulário

Eu tenho um formulário que nele contem alguns checkbox que quando fossem marcados eu queria que fosse atribuído o valor 1 para fazer o Insert no servidor, eu já vi como verificar se esta marcado, usando document.getElementByInput, mas eu atribuo a tag com o valor Vacina o valor de 1 por exemplo ?

Segue o código:

```
  <form id="Form" method="post" action="php/novoFilhote.php">
        <fieldset id="fieldset2">
        <input id="raca" placeholder="Raça" type="text" />
        <br />
        <input id="mae" placeholder="Mãe" type="text" />
        <br />
        <input id="pai" placeholder="Pai" type="text" />
        <br />
        <input id="preco" placeholder="Preço" type="number" />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        <label>Nascimento    </label><input id="nascimento" placeholder="Nascimento" type="date" />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        Doente: <input id="doente" name="item" type="checkbox"/>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        Vacinado: <input id="vacina" name="item" type="checkbox"/>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        Vermifugado: <input id="vermifugado" name="item" type="checkbox"/>
        </fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        Vendido: <input id="vendido" name="item" type="checkbox"/>
        </fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        <br />
        <fieldset  id="fieldset2">
        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
        <input id="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <button class='button2' type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function verificaChecks() {
    var aChk = document.getElementsByInput("checkbox"); 
    for (var i=0;i<aChk.length;i++){ 

        if (aChk[i].checked == true){ 
            //Aqui eu teria que atribuir '1'
            alert(aChk[i].value + " marcado.");
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

O comportamento padrão do checkbox é booleano, ou seja, somente será enviado seu valor caso ele esteja marcado.
No seu caso está faltando apenas adicionar os valores nos repectivos checkboxes com a tag `value` com a valor que preferir receber no servidor.
Segue em exemplo:

```
<input id="vacina" name="item" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
```

Como você tem mais de um `input`com mesmo nome, o último marcado de mesmo nome irá sobrescrever os anteriores, assim você deve atribuir um **nome único** a cada `input` para evitar isso. Por exemplo:

```
<input id="vacina" name="item[vacina]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<input id="vermifugado" name="item[vermifugado]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá segue abaixo alguns apontamentos para lhe ajudar na programação.

1) não é correto atribuir o mesmo nome de id a vários objetos "fieldset2"

2) não é correto atribuir id para a tag de fechamento `</fieldset  id="fieldset2">`

3) desconheço getElementByInput, utilize getElementsByName

4) coloque no final de todas as tag's checkbox a chamada para a função verificaChecks() como mostrado abaixo

```
<input id="vermifugado" name="item" type="checkbox" onclick="verificaChecks()"/>

<script>
var aChk = document.getElementsByName('item');
function verificaChecks() {

    for (var i=0;i<aChk.length;i++){ 

        if (aChk[i].checked){ 
            //Aqui eu teria que atribuir '1'
            aChk[i].value = 1;
            alert(aChk[i].id + ' = ' + aChk[i].value + " marcado.");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```